# pure CSS lightbox issue

Tags: css, lightbox

I'm working on a CSS photo gallery in CSS only and I've got a problem. I try to do a lightbox with 5 elements (pictures) and it worked perfectly. But when I want to add some new pictures, it doesn't work anymore and I don't know why. It's just like the last picture was displayed in full size in front of the other elements from the page (but with hidden property). So I see the page but I can't click the links... 
Here is the code :

```css
#GalleryContent {
 height: 817px;
 margin-top: 100px;
 margin-left: 55px;
}



#gallery a {
    text-decoration:none;
}

#gallery .item {
    width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    border: 5px solid #000;
    margin: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #d8c4a3;
}

#gallery .item a {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#gallery .item a img {
    height: 100%;
    align-self: center;
}

.lightbox {
    /** Hide the lightbox */
    opacity: 0;
    /** Apply basic lightbox styling */
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    top: -100%;
    left: 0;
    color:#333333;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}

.lightbox:target {
    /** Show lightbox when it is target */
    opacity: 1;
    outline: none;
    top: 0;
}

.lightbox .box {
      width: -webkit-min-content;
      width: -moz-min-content;
      width: min-content;
      min-width: 500px;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 20px 30px 20px 30px;
      background-color: #000;
      box-shadow: 0px 1px 26px -3px #000;
      font-family: 'IM Fell English', serif;
      color: #FFF;
}

.lightbox .title {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px #ccc solid;
    }

.lightbox .content {
    display: block;
    position: relative;

}

.lightbox .close {
    display:block;
    float:right;
    margin-top: -10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
 font-size: 0.8em;
 color: #FFF;
 border: 1px solid #FFF;
 padding: 0px 3px 2px 3px;
}

.lightbox #legend {
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 margin-top: -10px;

}

.clear {
    display:block;
    clear:both;

}

/* back and previous buttons */

.lightbox .next,
.lightbox .prev,
.lightbox .close {
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;

}

.prev {
    float:left;
    color:#FFF;
    padding-top: 12px;

 }

.next {
    float:right;
 color:#FFF;
 padding-top: 12px;

 }

.close {
    float:right;
}

.clear {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div id="GalleryContent">

                <section id="gallery">
                    <section class="item">
                        <a href="#img1">
                        <img src="images/galerie/voltigeurs-1.jpg">
                        </a>
                    </section>

                    <section class="item">
                        <a href="#img2">
                        <img src="images/galerie/voltigeurs-2.jpg">
                        </a>
                    </section>

                    <section class="item">
                    <a href="#img3">
                    <img src="images/galerie/voltigeurs-3.jpg">
                    </a>
                    </section>

                    <section class="item">
                    <a href="#img4">
                    <img src="images/galerie/voltigeurs-4.jpg">
                    </a>
                    </section>

                    <section class="item">
                    <a href="#img5">
                    <img src="images/galerie/voltigeurs-5.jpg">
                    </a>
                    </section>

                    <section class="item">
                    <a href="#img6">
                    <img src="images/galerie/voltigeurs-6.jpg">
                    </a>
                    </section>

                    <section class="item">
                    <a href="#img7">
                    <img src="images/galerie/voltigeurs-7.jpg">
                    </a>
                    </section>

                    <section class="item">
                    <a href="#img8">
                    <img src="images/galerie/voltigeurs-8.jpg">
                    </a>
                    </section>

                    <section class="item">
                    <a href="#img9">
                    <img src="images/galerie/voltigeurs-9.jpg">
                    </a>
                    </section>

                    <section class="item">
                    <a href="#img10">
                    <img src="images/galerie/voltigeurs-10.jpg">
                    </a>
                    </section>

                    <section class="item">
                    <a href="#img11">
                    <img src="images/galerie/voltigeurs-11.jpg">
                    </a>
                    </section>

                    <section class="item">
                    <a href="#img12">
                    <img src="images/galerie/voltigeurs-12.jpg">
                    </a>
                    </section>
                </section>
            </div>

            <!-- lightbox container hidden with CSS -->
            <div class="lightbox" id="img1">
                <div class="box">
                    <a class="close" href="#">x</a>
                    <div id="legend">1</div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <img src="images/galerie/voltigeurs-1.jpg">
                    </div>
                <!-- Previous Image Button -->
                <a class="prev" href="#"><img src="images/hand_right_white.png" width="40px"></a>
                <!-- Next Image Button -->
                <a class="next" href="#img2"><img src="images/hand_left_white.png" width="40px"></a>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="lightbox" id="img2">
                <div class="box">
                    <a class="close" href="#">x</a>
                    <div id="legend">2</div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <img src="images/galerie/voltigeurs-2.jpg">
                    </div>
                <!-- Previous Image Button -->
                <a class="prev" href="#img1"><img src="images/hand_right_white.png" width="40px"></a>
                <!-- Next Image Button -->
                <a class="next" href="#img3"><img src="images/hand_left_white.png" width="40px"></a>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="lightbox" id="img3">
                <div class="box">
                    <a class="close" href="#">x</a>
                    <div id="legend">3</div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <img src="images/galerie/voltigeurs-3.jpg">
                    </div>
                <!-- Previous Image Button -->
                <a class="prev" href="#img2"><img src="images/hand_right_white.png" width="40px"></a>
                <!-- Next Image Button -->
                <a class="next" href="#img4"><img src="images/hand_left_white.png" width="40px"></a>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="lightbox" id="img4">
                <div class="box">
                    <a class="close" href="#">x</a>
                    <div id="legend">4</div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <img src="images/galerie/voltigeurs-4.jpg">
                    </div>
                <!-- Previous Image Button -->
                <a class="prev" href="#img3"><img src="images/hand_right_white.png" width="40px"></a>
                <!-- Next Image Button -->
                <a class="next" href="#img5"><img src="images/hand_left_white.png" width="40px"></a>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="lightbox" id="img5">
                <div class="box">
                    <a class="close" href="#">x</a>
                    <div id="legend">5</div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <img src="images/galerie/voltigeurs-5.jpg">
                    </div>
                <!-- Previous Image Button -->
                <a class="prev" href="#img4"><img src="images/hand_right_white.png" width="40px"></a>
                <!-- Next Image Button -->
                <a class="next" href="#img6"><img src="images/hand_left_white.png" width="40px"></a>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="lightbox" id="img6">
                <div class="box">
                    <a class="close" href="#">x</a>
                    <div id="legend">6</div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <img src="images/galerie/voltigeurs-6.jpg">
                    </div>
                <!-- Previous Image Button -->
                <a class="prev" href="#img5"><img src="images/hand_right_white.png" width="40px"></a>
                <!-- Next Image Button -->
                <a class="next" href="#img7"><img src="images/hand_left_white.png" width="40px"></a>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="lightbox" id="img7">
                <div class="box">
                    <a class="close" href="#">x</a>
                    <div id="legend">7</div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <img src="images/galerie/voltigeurs-7.jpg">
                    </div>
                <!-- Previous Image Button -->
                <a class="prev" href="#img6"><img src="images/hand_right_white.png" width="40px"></a>
                <!-- Next Image Button -->
                <a class="next" href="#img8"><img src="images/hand_left_white.png" width="40px"></a>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="lightbox" id="img8">
                <div class="box">
                    <a class="close" href="#">x</a>
                    <div id="legend">8</div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <img src="images/galerie/voltigeurs-8.jpg">
                    </div>
                <!-- Previous Image Button -->
                <a class="prev" href="#img7"><img src="images/hand_right_white.png" width="40px"></a>
                <!-- Next Image Button -->
                <a class="next" href="#img9"><img src="images/hand_left_white.png" width="40px"></a>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="lightbox" id="img9">
                <div class="box">
                    <a class="close" href="#">x</a>
                    <div id="legend">9</div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <img src="images/galerie/voltigeurs-9.jpg">
                    </div>
                <!-- Previous Image Button -->
                <a class="prev" href="#img8"><img src="images/hand_right_white.png" width="40px"></a>
                <!-- Next Image Button -->
                <a class="next" href="#img10"><img src="images/hand_left_white.png" width="40px"></a>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="lightbox" id="img10">
                <div class="box">
                    <a class="close" href="#">x</a>
                    <div id="legend">10</div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <img src="images/galerie/voltigeurs-10.jpg">
                    </div>
                <!-- Previous Image Button -->
                <a class="prev" href="#img9"><img src="images/hand_right_white.png" width="40px"></a>
                <!-- Next Image Button -->
                <a class="next" href="#img11"><img src="images/hand_left_white.png" width="40px"></a>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="lightbox" id="img11">
                <div class="box">
                    <a class="close" href="#">x</a>
                    <div id="legend">11</div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <img src="images/galerie/voltigeurs-11.jpg">
                    </div>
                <!-- Previous Image Button -->
                <a class="prev" href="#img10"><img src="images/hand_right_white.png" width="40px"></a>
                <!-- Next Image Button -->
                <a class="next" href="#img12"><img src="images/hand_left_white.png" width="40px"></a>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="lightbox" id="img12">
                <div class="box">
                    <a class="close" href="#">x</a>
                    <div id="legend">12</div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <img src="images/galerie/voltigeurs-12.jpg">
                    </div>
                <!-- Previous Image Button -->
                <a class="prev" href="#img11"><img src="images/hand_right_white.png" width="40px"></a>
                <!-- Next Image Button -->
                <a class="next" href="#img1"><img src="images/hand_left_white.png" width="40px"></a>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The code snippet you have in your question appears to work correctly, ultimately what you'd best be doing is [getting firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and exploring in firebug any CSS clashes or gaps. Alternatively use [Lightbox 2](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)

Comment: Yes. I saw that this code was working here. That's why I don't understand where is the problem.
I will try firebug. But I don't want to change the lightbox now because it took me time to personalize it. 
Thank you!

Comment: What is strange is that the id appears on the url like so (local) :
Users/Documents//Site/galerie.html#im6
Like it was displayed on the page (with hidden feature).

Comment: Firebug CSS tab should tell you the order of priority of CSS styleson your page and it will tell you what is being cancelled out and what is cancelling it. That should shine a light towards finding the issue.

Comment: The id appears on the url because of your href. For example for img 1 href="#img1". This calls the sitepath you are in adding #img1.

Answer (score 0):

May be you want something like this.

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
#gallery{
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:auto;
    width:500px;
    padding:5px;
    height:800px;
    }
#thumbs{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border:1px solid green;
    padding:5px;
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
    }
#thumbs img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.lightbox{
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color:rgba(72,73,74,1);
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    }
.lightbox:target{
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
    transition:opacity 2s;
}
#outer{
    background-color:#FFF;
    width:min-content;
    height:400px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:30px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 35px #000000;
    padding:10px;
    }

#inner img{
    max-height:500px;
    max-width:800px;
    }   
.lightbox a{
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#666;
    }   
#cross{
    float:right;
    }
#next{
    float:right;
    }
```

---

```
<div id="gallery">
   <div id="thumbs">
      <a href="#lightbox1"><img src="img1.jpg"/></a>
     </div>
      <div id="thumbs">
      <a href="#lightbox2"><img src="img2.jpg"/></a>
     </div>
      <div id="thumbs">
      <a href="#lightbox3"><img src="img3.jpg"/></a>
     </div>
      <div id="thumbs">
      <a href="#lightbox4"><img src="img4.jpg"/></a>
     </div>
      <div id="thumbs">
      <a href="#lightbox5"><img src="img5.jpg"/></a>
     </div>
      <div id="thumbs">
      <a href="#lightbox6"><img src="img6.jpg"/></a>
     </div>
      <div id="thumbs">
      <a href="#lightbox7"><img src="img7.jpg"/></a>
     </div>
      <div id="thumbs">
      <a href="#lightbox8"><img src="img8.jpg"/></a>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="lightbox" id="lightbox1">
       <div id="outer">
         <p id="title">Image
         <a href="#" id="cross">X</a></p>
           <div id="inner">
            <img src="img1.jpg"/>
          </div>
          <p><a href="#lightbox2" id="next">Next</a>
          <a href="#lightbox8" id="prev">Previous</a></p>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="lightbox" id="lightbox2">
       <div id="outer">
         <p id="title">Image
         <a href="#" id="cross">X</a></p>
           <div id="inner">
            <img src="img2.jpg"/>
          </div>
          <p><a href="#lightbox3" id="next">Next</a>
          <a href="#lightbox1" id="prev">Previous</a></p>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="lightbox" id="lightbox3">
       <div id="outer">
         <p id="title">Image
         <a href="#" id="cross">X</a></p>
           <div id="inner">
            <img src="img3.jpg"/>
          </div>
          <p><a href="#lightbox4" id="next">Next</a>
          <a href="#lightbox2" id="prev">Previous</a></p>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="lightbox" id="lightbox4">
       <div id="outer">
         <p id="title">Image
         <a href="#" id="cross">X</a></p>
           <div id="inner">
            <img src="img4.jpg"/>
          </div>
          <p><a href="#lightbox5" id="next">Next</a>
          <a href="#lightbox3" id="prev">Previous</a></p>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="lightbox" id="lightbox5">
       <div id="outer">
         <p id="title">Image
         <a href="#" id="cross">X</a></p>
           <div id="inner">
            <img src="img5.jpg"/>
          </div>
          <p><a href="#lightbox6" id="next">Next</a>
          <a href="#lightbox4" id="prev">Previous</a></p>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="lightbox" id="lightbox6">
       <div id="outer">
         <p id="title">Image
         <a href="#" id="cross">X</a></p>
           <div id="inner">
            <img src="img6.jpg"/>
          </div>
          <p><a href="#lightbox7" id="next">Next</a>
          <a href="#lightbox5" id="prev">Previous</a></p>
       </div>
    </div>

     <div class="lightbox" id="lightbox7">
       <div id="outer">
         <p id="title">Image
         <a href="#" id="cross">X</a></p>
           <div id="inner">
            <img src="img7.jpg"/>
          </div>
          <p><a href="#lightbox8" id="next">Next</a>
          <a href="#lightbox6" id="prev">Previous</a></p>
       </div>
    </div>



    <div class="lightbox" id="lightbox7">
       <div id="outer">
         <p id="title">Image
         <a href="#" id="cross">X</a></p>
           <div id="inner">
            <img src="img7.jpg"/>
          </div>
          <p><a href="#lightbox8" id="next">Next</a>
          <a href="#lightbox6" id="prev">Previous</a></p>
       </div>
    </div>


     <div class="lightbox" id="lightbox8">
       <div id="outer">
         <p id="title">Image
         <a href="#" id="cross">X</a></p>
           <div id="inner">
            <img src="img8.jpg"/>
          </div>
          <p><a href="#lightbox9" id="next">Next</a>
          <a href="#lightbox7" id="prev">Previous</a></p>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Please check this videos:- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7ZhOczh35A  & https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=82SwGTvM_DU